# Install newer package version from trusty-backports

Tags: 14.04, package-management, backport

In an ubuntu 14.04 system with the latest updates:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 1.5.4

$ apt-cache policy ansible
ansible:
  Installed: 1.5.4+dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1.5.4+dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.7.1+dfsg-1~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        100 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64     Packages
 *** 1.5.4+dfsg-1 0
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

1. How can I install the newest version of ansible (1.7.1) from trusty-backports ?
2. Is it in general safe to use the packages from trusty-backports ?

Comment: download from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ansible/1.7.1+dfsg-1

Answer (score 11):

Found the answers here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports

To install:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ansible/trusty-backports
```

The link above contains information about stability and security support for Backports.

Answer (score 0):

For newer Ubuntu versions this will fill the correct backport name for you:

```
sudo apt install -t `lsb_release -cs`-backports ansible
```

Where `-cs` == `--codename` + `--short`.